# moq: How do I setup behaviour of constructor in generated proxy?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have an abstract class (let's call it `AbstractOutputter`). When I derive from it, I make calls to a protected method in the constructor of the derived class.

**AbstractOutputter**

```
public abstract class IOutputter<T>
{
  protected void Write(Func<T, string> output)
  {
   ... 
  }
}
```

**Derived class**

```
public class WotsitOutputter: AbstractOutputter<Wotsit>
{
  public WotsitOutputter()
  {
    Write(x => x.Property1.ToString());
    Write(x => x.Property2.ToString());
  }
}
```

The pattern is identical to creating validator classes in FluentValidation:

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

I would like Moq to create me a class deriving from `AbstractOutputter`, in order to unit test how it responds to various permutations of calls to `Write()`.. I would need to do something like this:

```
Mock<AbstractOutputter<Wotsit>> mockOutputter = new Mock<AbstractOutputter<Wotsit>>();
// Instruct Moq to make various calls to protected method in constructor of mock class
```

Is it possible to do this? Can I somehow tell Moq to perform certain actions within the constructor of the proxy it creates? Or will I need to define real classes extending `AbstractOutputter` just for unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to put this to bed: I conclude that Moq cannot do this.

In the end I just defined some simple implementations of `AbstractOutputter<Wotsit>` for the purpose of testing.